# R data editor(XQuartz) very slow

Tags: r

When I use `fix()` in **terminal**/**R Studio** the **XQuartz version of R data editor** is invoked. However this editor is way slower than the one used by the official R.app.

Xquartz R data editor is so slow that I can identify every single update on cells when loading the data with my bare eyes. I have XQuartz 2.7.8, running in Mac OS El Capitan.

I wonder is there anyway to invoke the "official" editor instead of the XQuartz version?

Comment: For what it is worth, in RStudio you can double-click the dataset in the upper-left "Environment" tab to open the data in RStudio itself. It's quite a bit nicer than fix()

Answer (score 0):

I may or may not be the correct useR to answer this question because I almost never use `fix` or the function it depends on, `edit`. I also don't know how to find "the one used by the official R.app".  I instead use `[<-` with logical indexing for my data management "fixes". I'm wondering if you are attempting to do editing operations on large objects, for which invoking a data editor might not be the most efficient strategy?

Nonetheless, I looked at the code of `edit` and notice that at the top of the function is some OS-specific code that may offer a way to modify your environment:

```
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix" && .Platform$GUI != "AQUA") 
        if (.Platform$GUI == "unknown" || Sys.getenv("DISPLAY") == 
            "") 
            return(edit.default(name, ...))
    is.vector.unclass <- function(x) is.vector(unclass(x))
    if (length(name) && !all(sapply(name, is.vector.unclass) | 
        sapply(name, is.factor))) 
        stop("can only handle vector and factor elements")
    if (grepl("darwin", R.version$os)) 
        check_for_XQuartz()
```

When you are running R.app you get "AQUA" for `.Platform$GUI`, and for my machine I get "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.KImNTikz8K/org.macosforge.xquartz:0" from `Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")`. You can change that by using `Sys.setenv("DISPLAY" = "")` or `Sys.setenv("DISPLAY" = "quartz")`

Comment: If you run the R console and type `fix(Boston)`, a data editor window will appear. This editor is way faster than the editors invoked by other R instances, e.g. Rstudio.

Comment: P.S. I am not actually trying to edit any data in that editor. For me it is a great tool to take a quick glance at the data. A great tutorial I am reading also recommend it as a great peeking tool. *An introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications iin R*

Comment: That book would be Hastie and Tibshirani Lite?

Comment: After trying everything, I uninstalled the quartz that I had installed with brew and reinstalled from .dmg. Now everything works very fast.

Comment: Mixing brew installation of system packages with the CRAN distributed binary installer for R is specifically advised against by Simon Urbanek, the maintainer of the Mac R fork.